# integrating spatialite and php (sqlite3) on windows platform

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, php

anyone can give me an explanation about how to integrate spatialite with php(sqlite3)-windows platforms.

I have tried to refer from this link http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/spatialite-cookbook/html/php.html

But I do not understand is why the error message appears as follows.

```
"Warning SQLite3::loadextension(), Not supported in multithreaded Web Servers"
```

i use libspatialite-2.dll

Answer (score 1):

The message is explicit. Your server settings does not support loading extension from script like so :

```
$db->loadExtension('libspatialite.so');
```

See if you could load it directly from the *php.ini*

Comment: i've done the configuration in `php.ini`, i edited a `sqlite3.extension_dir=libspatialite-2.dll` but it's just stay the same error messages. If i write the wrong code on it? Another info, i use xampp 1.7

Comment: you must restart apache

Comment: i've already include it, in my way to edit the `php.ini` always restart my apache.

but whether the problem was appear is because i using xampp, not using a php and apache which are mutually exclusive (separated each of them)?

Comment: check if *enable_dl = On* is uncommented on your php.ini. If it is and it does not still work I guess you would have to install Apache and PHP manually (which is not a big deal ....)